# Manuel Tests Code coverage on Sonarqube

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I would like to get code coverage using JaCoCo and display it on Sonarqube after several manual and automated End-to-End tests. Currently, we can also collect `JUnit` tests coverage which is triggered during `mvn test`

It looks like I need to instrument the code on JVM using 
[Jacoco Agent](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html). But I need some examples to this. First of all, I need to know where can I get Jacoco agents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have maven already up and running, watch it's output. Jacoco prepares an argument line for surefire that contains a pointer to the agent:

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.5.201505241946:prepare-agent (pre-unit-test) @ examples ---
[INFO] jacoco.surefireArgLine set to -javaagent:E:\\mvnrepository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.5.201505241946\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946-runtime.jar=destfile=E:\\examples\\target\\jacoco-ut.exec,append=true,includes=org.example.*
```

The generated argline is basically the same as you may use for the JVM you want to generate coverage data for:

```
-javaagent:E:\\mvnrepository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.5.201505241946\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946-runtime.jar=destfile=E:\\example\\target\\jacoco-ut.exec,append=true,includes=org.example.*
```

After you've done with the manual tests you have to re-run sonar analysis to pick up the unit test results. Note that the destfile in the argline must point to a location in your maven structure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works great. Is it possible to merge jacoco reports? We have several exec files now which are created by different sub-maven projects however they fail in sonar report when I push to sonar from the submodule. Maybe I should try to push from parent project?